# figure different numbering \only - beamer

Tags: beamer, floats

I am using beamer and i want to create a set of slides with the same title, but different content so i use the command \only. Per each `\only{}` i inserted different pictures, but they appear with the same number, even though i would like them to be numbered sequentially.

Example:

```
\begin{frame}{Regional recording system}
\only<1>{

...
     \begin{figure}[r]
          \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{KNet_stationsMap}
          \caption{\label{fig:KNet_stationsMap}K-Net network {\tiny \textbf{\cite{ref5}}}.}
     \end{figure}
...

}
\only<2>{
...
        \begin{figure}[c]
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{KikNet_stationsMap}
            \caption{\label{fig:KikNet_stationsMap}Kik-Net network {\tiny \textbf{\cite{ref1}}}.}
        \end{figure}
...
}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: try `\addtocounter{figure}{1}` before the second figure

Comment: @PipsCats If [samcarter's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193039/21891) solved your problem, please *accept* it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Converting the previous comment into an answer]

To work around this problem, you can add

```
\addtocounter{figure}{1}
```

before the second figure. This is a way to increase the number by hand.

Comment: I was trying to do the opposite: let 2 figures (same figure in 2 sequential slides) have the same number, changed the "1" to "-1" and it worked just fine! Thank you